# Referencia de forein key, com o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, orm

To tendo uma dificuldade ao fazer um *insert*, pois o EF, indica que tá havendo erro na referencia da tabela. Mas, no meu *config*, eu indico qual é a *foreing key*.

Meu config:

```
public class TestDriveConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestDrive>
{
    public TestDriveConfig()
    {
        ToTable("TestDrive");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.ExpireDate).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.OpeningDate).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.UserId).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);
    }
}
```

O erro que o EF apresenta, ao realizar o insert:

> "Foreign key violation [TestDrive :: UserId]. The key value [2] does not exists in the referenced table [vw__usuario :: codigo].. Error code: RelationError"

Comment: O seu banco de dados já possui dados? Me parece que esse erro vem de tentar criar uma chave externa apontando para um item que não existe.

Comment: Eu testou trabalhando com testes, faço a inserção de dados, pra depois inserir nessa tabela.

Comment: Acho que você inseriu um valor de chave externa 2 para user antes de criar ou alterar a relação. O EF não pode criar a relação porque essa chave externa apontaria para uma linha que não existe.

Comment: Você pode colocar os dois *Models* na sua pergunta?

Comment: Resolvido o problema? Senão, tem como colocar o código das classes na pergunta para tentarmos ajudá-lo?